# How to read serial data correctly through Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am using Matlab to read data from a serial port coming through a microprocessor. The data is in hexadecimal format with each sample of 4 bytes(32 bits). When I read this data, I get some random sequence of numbers which don't match the transmitted data. Below is my code

```
s = serial('COM16'); %assigns the object s to serial port

set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 128); %number of bytes in inout buffer
set(s, 'FlowControl', 'none');
set(s, 'BaudRate', 921600);
set(s, 'Parity', 'none');
set(s, 'DataBits', 8);
set(s, 'StopBit', 1);
set(s, 'Timeout',100);
%clc;

disp(get(s,'Name'));
prop(1)=(get(s,'BaudRate'));
prop(2)=(get(s,'DataBits'));
prop(3)=(get(s, 'StopBit'));
prop(4)=(get(s, 'InputBufferSize'));

disp([num2str(prop)]);

fopen(s);           %opens the serial port

data = fscanf(s);

fclose(s); %close the serial port
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong do that I can get the correct heart sound.
thanks

Comment: Can you adjust your microcontroller's baudrate? If so, could you try with a lower baudrate? 921600 is quite high. 115200 maybe?

Comment: Also, did you try with a terminal program?

Comment: Sure, I will give it a try. Actually, the algorithm requires my UART speed to be quite high, that's why I set it to 921600.

Comment: What do you mean by terminal program? I don't know about it. Can you explain it?

Comment: Terminal programs allow you to connect to a serial port and send/receive data. You can try [Eltima's program](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-terminal/). It is a 14 day trial. There was a good freeware one but I can't remember the name right now. I will try to find it when I have the chance.

Comment: Hey, I tried with lower Baud rate and it is working perfectly :)
Thanks a lot. I just have to see if my hardware allows me to use this Baud Rate. In case if it doesn't is there any way to make it work at higher baud rate?

Comment: I wouldn't know about hardware :) Maybe you can try [electronics.se]

Comment: My hardware limitation doesn't allow be go below 921600, so I am thinking I would switch to C or Java. Any idea if 921600 baud rate is acceptable there?

Comment: I am getting it working in C :)

Comment: @HebeleHododo Could you post your observation as an answer to prevent the question from remaining unsolved?

Comment: I realized that I haven't written the freeware terminal program's name. It is [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/), in case a future visitor needs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lower the baudrate to something more standard, like 115200.

You can also try with a terminal program.

Answer (score 0):

```
serialOne=serial('COM1', 'BaudRate', 9600);

fopen(serialOne);

fprintf(serialOne,'textFile.txt'); <<<---this is for write  (for read, use fscanf)

fclose(serialOne);
```