# Why do I need to query twice for correct reply using serial port in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I need to communicate with an older temperature controller that only has a serial interface (RS-232). 
I'm using Matlab and my PC doesn't have a serial port. Therefore I'm using a serial-to-USB adapter.

After a couple hours of struggling, I finally got a connection. But I always need to query twice to get the reply I expect.

For example:

asking for temperature (last query was temp too)

```
>> query(s,'in_pv_00')
ans =
      23.49
```

asking for temperature

```
>> query(s,'in_pv_00')
ans =
      23.49
```

asking for version

```
>> query(s,'version')
ans =
      23.49
```

I still get the temp value
Then, if I query for version again

```
>> query(s,'version')
ans =
      JULABO HIGHTECH D-SERIES VERSION 4.0
```

I finally get the version
now, asking for temp, I will still get the version one more time before I will get the temp

```
>> query(s,'in_pv_00')
ans =
      JULABO HIGHTECH D-SERIES VERSION 4.0
>> query(s,'in_pv_00')
ans =
      23.49
```

That's the port settings I use

```
s = serial('COM6');
set(s,'BaudRate',4800,'DataBits',7,'StopBits',1);
set(s,'Parity','even','Terminator',{'CR','CR'},'FlowControl','hardware');
fopen(s);
```

Comment: Only thing that looks odd to me (Not a matlab guy specifically but I've done plenty of COM port debugging )


set(s,'Parity','even','Terminator',{'CR','CR'},'FlowControl','hardware'); 

Why is this CR CR, normally you would see something like CR, LF or just LF for Linux systems, but it all depends on what the device is configured to do that's talking over that serial port. Also double check that the BaudRate, Databits, Stop Bits, and Parity are correct between your host machine and the device that's talking to the serial port.

Comment: I set BaudRate, Databits, Stop Bits and Parity to the values in the manual of the temp controller, and checked if they were still set that way. The CR CR I got from a matlab script that was running on older PC with a real serial port and was working. That was also my first guess, but when I change it to just LF, it doesn't work at all. I will try your other suggestion.

Comment: If you can find the manual for the temp controller it might tell you what's going on. It seems like the terminator is the issue here, but I"m not certain what set() exactly does either in MatLab I'd take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233394/how-to-read-serial-data-correctly-through-matlab try Mirco Widmer's suggestion except with fscanf hopefully the file will populate with something. Then open the file with hexEditor and look at what the end of lines are. Since you do receive data I'd have to imagine your Baudrate/DataBits and StopBits are set properly.

Comment: I would try using something like Bray's Terminal to confirm the characters transmitted and received. https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/

Comment: Thank you for your help, although I couldn't figure out what the culprit was, it works now. I flush the buffer at the beginning and haven't had the issue since

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still could not find the culprit for the behavior.
But I flush the buffer whenever I start a measurement and so far the error hasn't occurred this way.